# How can I use easing effects to this div that expands onclick, as well as fade in effects on the elements inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, easing

I have two problems,

1)    I have a div that expands onclick, (.panel) how can I use easing on it so it opens in a smooth way?

2)    how can I make the ul list within the expanding div (.panel) fade in a few mili seconds after the div has expanded?

```
<div id="effect" class="mores" style="background-color: brown">
<div class="panel">click
    <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
 var next_move = "expand";
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".panel").click(function () {
     console.log(next_move);
     var css = {};
     if (next_move == "expand") {
         css = {
             width: '210px',
             height: '170px'
         };
         next_move = "shrink";
     } else {
         css = {
             width: '30px',
             height: '20px'
         };
         console.log('hi');
         next_move = "expand";
     }
     $(this).animate(css, 200);
 });
});




     .panel {
      width: 30px;
      height: 21px;
      overflow: hidden;
      color:white;
      background-color: grey;
  }
      .panel ul {
       margin-left:10%;
       color:white;
 }
      .mores {
      width: 210px;
      height: 170px;
      overflow: hidden;
 }
```

here is the fiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lycrest15/z2p0r5s9/2/)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something, tell me if that's what you expected. http://jsfiddle.net/z2p0r5s9/11/

```
<div id="effect" class="mores" style="background-color: brown">
<div class="panel">click
    <ul style="display:none">
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel {
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color:white;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

JS

```
 var next_move = "expand";
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $(".panel").click(function () {
     console.log(next_move);
     var css = {};
     if (next_move == "expand") {
         css = {
             width: '210px',
             height: '170px'
         };
         next_move = "shrink";
          setTimeout(function(){
             $('ul').fadeIn();                 
         },2000);
     } else {
         css = {
             width: '30px',
             height: '20px'
         };
         console.log('hi');
         next_move = "expand";

     }
     $(this).animate(css, 200);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you pretend?

```
var next_move = "expand";
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".panel").click(function () {
         console.log(next_move);
         var css = {};
         if (next_move == "expand") {
             css = {
                 width: '210px',
                 height: '170px'
             };
             next_move = "shrink";
         } else {
             css = {
                 width: '30px',
                 height: '20px'
             };
             console.log('hi');
             next_move = "expand";
         }
         $(this).animate(css, 200, function(){
             setTimeout(function() {
                 $(".options").fadeIn()
              }, 75);
         });
     });

 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lycrest15/z2p0r5s9/2/

It is using default easing but you can change it to the proper way you want. Just see documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/